# Optimus Nvidia not working anymore (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

After a recent automatic security update (Ubuntu 14.04), none of my games using the nvidia driver (I have a laptop with optimus/bumblebee/nvidia) does not work anymore. I don't use the "dangerous" packages, only the security and recommended updates. Because I use my laptop also for working, I mean for serious things :-). Any information somewhere ?